# What are existing tools to test Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I need to take some real world examples and apply it in a particular tool which I can run the algorithms by giving  inputs. Can anyone suggest some good tools.

The algorithms I intend to test:

1. A* algo
2. DFS / BFS
3. DLS / Iterative Deepening DFS / Bi-directional / UCS

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

The classic robot on a grid, with obstacles, can be solved using all of these:

There is a robot, starting at location `S`, need to get to a target `T`, on a grid containing walls.

- your heuristic function for A* could be [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).
- BFS/Iterative deepening search always work for these search problems
- DFS is not complete!!! and so might be stuck in an infinite loop.
- Since you have a single target and a single source, bi-directional search can also be applied here.

Real life application is of couse, moving a robot on a 2d space.